# Compilation of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors, pdftex, compiling

I have a latex document which is compiling properly. The message on compiling is

*Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "template_Book_23June2014_V2".tex*

*This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning input file cases.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in cases.ind. Transcript written in cases.ilg.*

*This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning input file legislation.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in legislation.ind. Transcript written in legislation.ilg.*

*Process exited normally*

```
    \documentclass[]{book}
    \title{Alpha}
    \author{Beta \and Theta }
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[style=oscola,eutreaty=alternative,ibidtracker=false, indexing=cite, 
     backend=biber]{biblatex}
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \usepackage{genmpage}
   \usepackage{imakeidx}
   \usepackage[style=british]{csquotes} 
   \makeindex[name=cases, title={Table of Cases}]
   \makeindex[name=legislation, title={Table of Legislation}]
    %Bibliography resource
    \addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
   \begin{document}
   \maketitle
   \tableofcontents
   \frontmatter
   \mainmatter
   \backmatter
   \printbibliography[nottype=commentary,nottype=jurisdiction, nottype=legislation,
   nottype=legal]
   \end{document}
```

However when i try compiling the .bib file i am getting the following message:

*Could not start default compiler: Pdflatex*
*Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Bibliography".tex*

The code for my Bibliography.bib file is:

```
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{Erdos01} P. Erd\H os, \emph{A selection of problems and
      results in combinatorics}, Recent trends in combinatorics (Matrahaza,
      1995), Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2001, pp. 1--6.
     \end{thebibliography}}
```

I am a complete newbie to latex am trying to get me head around it.

Comment: That's not a valid bib-file. And also a bib-file is never compiled, only read (in your case biber should read it).

Comment: The safest way to do it is using a bibliography manager such as JabRef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bib file is pure TeX code. Insert it with `\input`:

```
[ ... ]
\mainmatter
\backmatter
\input{Bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

and do not define `\addbibresource`. The correct way is to create a bib data base which is far different to the TeX code of your `Bibliography.bib`

Comment: thank you. The same works fine now. The reason i had created the bibliography manually was that i want to utilise OSCOLA citation, and was not sure if jabref would cover the same.